# Flutter: Is multi package initializing messing up with performance?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-amplify

In my Flutter app, I am using Firebase messaging for notifications and Amazon amplify to talk with S3. Following is my main.dart file. Does having all those initializations cause the app to slow down? When my users are opening the app, the splash screen takes a while to load.

Also if not the way I did, what is the best way to initialize it?

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyAppInitial());
}

class MyAppInitial extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppInitial({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppInitialState createState() => _MyAppInitialState();
}

class _MyAppInitialState extends State<MyAppInitial> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  String? _deviceToken;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeApp();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeApp() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    configureAmplify();
    final appDocumentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    HydratedBloc.storage =
        await HydratedStorage.build(storageDirectory: appDocumentDirectory);

    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    // Firebase messaging setup
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    _deviceToken = await messaging.getToken();

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();

    setState(() {
      _initialized = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_initialized) {
      return SplashScreen();
    }

    return MyApp(deviceToken: _deviceToken);
  }
}

void configureAmplify() async {
  final auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();
  final storage = AmplifyStorageS3();
  await amplifyFlutter.Amplify.addPlugins([auth, storage]);

  try {
    await amplifyFlutter.Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```